# Fatal adult-onset blood/vascular disorder

Tags: blood, cardiovascular-disease, disorders, anemia

I'd like to know if there's a blood or vascular disease/disorder that fits, or could conceivably fit, all the following criteria, even if only in theory:

1. Present from birth
2. Onset of symptoms, or a sudden severe increase of symptoms, in young adulthood (anywhere from age 20 to 40, let's say)
3. Relatively high fatality rate
4. Incurable (though not necessarily untreatable)
5. Not restricted to developing societies; can affect upper-middle class Westerners

I've landed on sickle-cell anemia as a promising candidate, although I don't know whether it can fulfill criterion #2.